# Managing RadioButton with RelativeLayouts

Tags: android, android-layout, coding-style

I have an activity where the user would have to choose one option from a list.

For example:

```
<relativeLayout>
   <relativeLayout> <radiobutton> <textview>
   <relativeLayout> <radiobutton> <textview> <edittext> <textview>
   <relativeLayout> <radiobutton> <textview> <spinner> <textview>
<relativeLayout>
```

So only one radio button can be chosen at any one time.

The best way to do this would probably be to use a radioGroup to manage these buttons. As the relativeLayouts are in place, the radioGroup cannot be used to ensure only one radio button is checked at any one time.

Other than managing the radioButton behaviour manually (i.e. onClick, set other radio buttons to unchecked), is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

yes ..
If you put the condition into your  xml layout it will done.
like:

```
RadioButton android:checked="false"

<RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical"

            id="@+id/group1">

            <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:text="Q1: What is Android?" android:textStyle="bold" />

            <RadioButton android:checked="false"

                    android:text="@string/radio_group_1_option1" id="@+id/option1" />

            <RadioButton android:checked="false"

                    android:text="@string/radio_group_1_option2" id="@+id/option2" />

            <RadioButton android:checked="false"

                    android:text="@string/radio_group_1_option3" id="@+id/option3" />

    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Oh.!!@PareshMayani Is it wrong then guide yaar?? I am  always ready to learn from you..

Comment: I think this is not the perfect solution because he has already mentioned about to use RadioGroup.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that if i use the radiogroup with my layout design, the relative layouts would be nested within the radiogroup. I've tried it and the radiogroup behaviour stops working (i.e. multiple radio buttons can be selected)